# Need help from CSS purist!

Tags: html, css

I'm beginning to use CSS more and more but I'm not sure if I'm using it as intended in all cases.

I have classes named things like 'box' that will wrap the content inside it with a border, which seems like good CSS to me.

On the other hand I have classes like 'margin-right-5' and 'float-left' that sets the css to `margin-right: 5px` and `float:left` respectively. I'm wondering if this is **good practice.**

Then in my markup I'd do something like:

```
<div class="box float-left margin-right-5">
    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

Sometimes I may want to float right or not have a margin at all and still use the 'box' class, so I use several classes in order to make the css more flexible.

Am I destroying the principles of CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have presentational class name values. The values should dictate the type of content that is there. `.content-box` for example. Use the most specific name you can, like `warning` or `error-dialog` or `primary-content`.

If you name something `left-align` and later on in the future you have this `left-align` class on 10-20 separate templates/include files, it won't be meaningful when the client decides to want to have that element right-aligned.

Just set whatever rules you need to, and you can make general rules for generic classes and override them if need be.

```
.content-box { 
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Using your way, you'd define a class for every property-value combination...

```
<div class="align-left float-left clear-right margin-left-five">
```

This is a mess. **Avoid at all costs.**

Comment: Yeah, you should seperate the contents (whatever goes in HTML) from the presentation (CSS) if you want to get the CSS principles right.

Comment: Additionally, though it's kind of ugly, if the class styles need to be overridden in just one instance, you could use inline styles via the style attribute on the tag.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will change my CSS accordingly

Answer (score 2):

"Am I destroying the principles of CSS?"

Short answer:

## Yes

Long answer:

At least you're checking your practice. Classes should be descriptive of the object and semantics, not of the style.

Here are some good classes:

- warning
- error
- sidebar
- box
- block
- name
- title
- song

Here are some bad classes:

- yellow
- left
- wide
- small
- clearfix<sup>†</sup>

†Edit to add a class that I no longer use as it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rethinking your naming conventions.

With the sample above you could end up with class="margin-right-[0 through 1000+].

**It's better to describe what the item is versus attributes about it**

ie.

```
<div class="header">
   <ul class="nav">
       <li>Home</li>
       <li>etc</li>
       <li> ... </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And then add the padding/margin/etc as needed.

Remember to use proper html elements instead of making everything divs (a.k.a [divitis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div#Overuse)).  Titles should use  tags, etc.